# why offsetX and offsetY return different value in firefox and chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am writing an drawing web application, use mousemove event's offsetX and offsetY, it works fine in chrome, but not in firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 300px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <svg class="svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0,0,600,600">
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/600/600" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600"></image>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <script>
    let box = document.querySelector('.svg');
    box.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, e.target);
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the above code, in chrome, the offsetX is between 0 and 500px, in firefox, the offsetX is between 0 and 600px, why they are not same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known specs bug](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1508), it isn't clear how browsers should calculate this value for <svg> layout elements and we end up with inter-op issues like that.

Since you want Chrome's behavior, you can simply disable the pointer-events on your <image> element, so that the <svg> receives it directly:

```js
let box = document.querySelector('.svg');
box.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  console.log(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.svg image {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg class="svg" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0,0,600,600">
    <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/600/600" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```